# Universal Logic for finding qibla direction

Tags: java, android, location, latitude-longitude, compass-geolocation

I am very keen on knowing an universal qibla direction logic as I want to implement in my islamic android app. I have just obtained latitude and longitude of the user and irrespective of any lat, lon I want to find qibla direction for that person whether the person is in UK, US, India, Sri Lanka or any where.

I found this formula, and don't know how exactly it works:

```
float lonDelta = (lon2 - lon1);
float y = Math.sin(lonDelta) * Math.cos(lat2);
float x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lonDelta);
float brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg();
```

Please help me in knowing exact formula.

Answer (score 8):

instead of using this formula

```
float lonDelta = (lon2 - lon1);
float y = Math.sin(lonDelta) * Math.cos(lat2);
float x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) *  Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lonDelta);
float brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg();
```

you can simple use bearingTo in this way

```
  Location userLoc=new Location("service Provider");
    //get longitudeM Latitude and altitude of current location with gps class and  set in userLoc
    userLoc.setLongitude(longitude); 
    userLoc.setLatitude(latitude);
    userLoc.setAltitude(altitude);

   Location destinationLoc = new Location("service Provider");
  destinationLoc.setLatitude(21.422487); //kaaba latitude setting
  destinationLoc.setLongitude(39.826206); //kaaba longitude setting
  float bearTo=userLoc.bearingTo(destinationLoc);
```

bearingTo will give you a range from -180 to 180, which will confuse things a bit. We will need to convert this value into a range from 0 to 360 to get the correct rotation.

This is a table of what we really want, comparing to what bearingTo gives us

```
+-----------+--------------+
| bearingTo | Real bearing |
+-----------+--------------+
| 0         | 0            |
+-----------+--------------+
| 90        | 90           |
+-----------+--------------+
| 180       | 180          |
+-----------+--------------+
| -90       | 270          |
+-----------+--------------+
| -135      | 225          |
+-----------+--------------+
| -180      | 180          |
+-----------+--------------+
```

so we have to add this code after bearTo

```
// If the bearTo is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.

  if (bearTo < 0) {
    bearTo = bearTo + 360;
    //bearTo = -100 + 360  = 260;
}
```

you need to implements the SensorEventListener and its functions(onSensorChanged,onAcurracyChabge) and write all the code inside onSensorChanged

**Complete code is here for Direction of Qibla compass**

```
 public class QiblaDirectionCompass extends Service implements SensorEventListener{
 public static ImageView image,arrow;

// record the compass picture angle turned
private float currentDegree = 0f;
private float currentDegreeNeedle = 0f;
Context context;
Location userLoc=new Location("service Provider");
// device sensor manager
private static SensorManager mSensorManager ;
private Sensor sensor;
public static TextView tvHeading;
   public QiblaDirectionCompass(Context context, ImageView compass, ImageView needle,TextView heading, double longi,double lati,double alti ) {

    image = compass;
    arrow = needle;


    // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he heading
    tvHeading = heading;
    userLoc.setLongitude(longi);
    userLoc.setLatitude(lati);
    userLoc.setAltitude(alti);

  mSensorManager =  (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    if(sensor!=null) {
        // for the system's orientation sensor registered listeners
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);//SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_Fastest
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
this.context =context;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME); //SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_Fastest
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
Toast.makeText(context, "Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onDestroy();

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

float degree = Math.round(sensorEvent.values[0]);
float head = Math.round(sensorEvent.values[0]);
float bearTo;
Location destinationLoc = new Location("service Provider");

destinationLoc.setLatitude(21.422487); //kaaba latitude setting
destinationLoc.setLongitude(39.826206); //kaaba longitude setting
float bearTo=userLoc.bearingTo(destinationLoc);

  //bearTo = The angle from true north to the destination location from the point we're your currently standing.(asal image k N se destination taak angle )

  //head = The angle that you've rotated your phone from true north. (jaise image lagi hai wo true north per hai ab phone jitne rotate yani jitna image ka n change hai us ka angle hai ye)



GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField( Double.valueOf( userLoc.getLatitude() ).floatValue(), Double
        .valueOf( userLoc.getLongitude() ).floatValue(),
        Double.valueOf( userLoc.getAltitude() ).floatValue(),
        System.currentTimeMillis() );
head -= geoField.getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north into true north

if (bearTo < 0) {
    bearTo = bearTo + 360;
    //bearTo = -100 + 360  = 260;
}

//This is where we choose to point it
float direction = bearTo - head;

// If the direction is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
if (direction < 0) {
    direction = direction + 360;
}
 tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees" );

RotateAnimation raQibla = new RotateAnimation(currentDegreeNeedle, direction, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
raQibla.setDuration(210);
raQibla.setFillAfter(true);

arrow.startAnimation(raQibla);

currentDegreeNeedle = direction;

// create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree, -degree, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

// how long the animation will take place
ra.setDuration(210);


// set the animation after the end of the reservation status
ra.setFillAfter(true);

// Start the animation
image.startAnimation(ra);

currentDegree = -degree;
}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

xml code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/flag_pakistan">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Heading: 0.0" />
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageCompass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/images_compass"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/needle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees" );                 What's degree here? You havn't declared it anywhere!

Comment: Kashif Bro, Where did you call QiblaDirectionCompas?? Did you miss something? or other clas?? if so.. Then please post it here too.

Comment: It is not calling in this class. it will call from the main class or other class depend on you.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadKashifArif would you like to show me the screenshot of your qibla app?

Comment: i had stopped working on it, now i am studding and it is not possible at the moment, although code has been shared. if you have problem to understanding on it you can contact me at here.

Answer (score 2):

Use following method to get accurate qibla direction.

```
public double calculateQibla(double latitude, double longitude){
    double phiK = 21.4 * Math.PI / 180.0;
    double lambdaK = 39.8 * Math.PI/180.0;
    double phi = latitude*Math.PI/180.0;
    double lambda = longitude*Math.PI/180.0;
    double psi = 180.0/Math.PI * Math.atan2(Math.sin(lambdaK-lambda),Math.cos(phi)*Math.tan(phiK)-Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(lambdaK-lambda));
    return Math.round(psi);
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: what value does it return finally ?

Comment: if will return bearing to Kaaba.

Comment: Hello. use 21.422487 and 39.826206 for lat long

Answer (score 0):

Since you first have to determine the user's location anyway, you'll have a `Location` object.

The `Location` object has a `bearingTo()` method which takes another `Location` object as a parameter. That should be the coordinates of the Kaaba in Mecca. (As I've understood.)

You can use it like:

```
Location kaabaLocation = new Location("");
kaabaLocation.setLatitude(21.4225);
kaabaLocation.setLongitude(39.8262);
float kaabaBearing = userLocation.bearingTo(kaabaLocation);
```

So Android already has the mathematics built in.