# Logic for finding qibla direction using accelerometer and magnetic field sensors

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-sensors

I am trying to implement the logic for finding the qibla direction.

I used `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` and copied the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036933/universal-logic-for-finding-qibla-direction)

```java
mSensorManager =  (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
```

but I found that the `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` is deprecated and instead, I used accelerometer and magnetic field sensors from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003787/how-can-i-replace-type-orientation-is-deprecated-for-android-4-0-3)

here is my code now

```
private void registerSensor() {
        mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
```

```
private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        float degree;
        float head;
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (lastKnownLocation == null || image == null || arrow == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                mGravity = event.values;
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
                mGeomagnetic = event.values;
            if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
                float R[] = new float[9];
                float I[] = new float[9];
                boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
                if (success) {
                    float orientation[] = new float[3];
                    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                    degree = orientation[2]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
                    head = orientation[0];
                }
            }
```

I am trying to get the degree and head. what am I doing wrong here?